# Alignment about the chemical equation

Tags: alignment, chemfig

`\schemestart $\chemfig{C(-[:50])(-[:130])=[:-150]C(-[:150])-[:-90]C(-[:-150])=[:-30]C(-[:-50])(-[:-130])}$ \+{0mm,0mm,-1cm} $\chemfig{[:144]O*5(-(=[:72]O)-=-(=[:-72]O)-)}$ \arrow{->} $\chemfig{*6((-[:-150])-(-[:-135])(-[:-45])-(*5(-(=[:-72]O)-O-(=[:72]O)-))--(-[:135])(-[:45])-(-[:150])=)}$ \schemestop`

The arrangement of the equation is very weird but there is no central atom in the first molecule. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{\phantom{C}-[:150,,,,draw=none]C(=[:30]C(-[:50])(-[:130]))-[6]C=[:-30]C(-[:-50])(-[:-130])}
    \+
    \chemfig{[:144]O*5(-(=[:72]O)-=-(=[:-72]O)-)}
    \arrow{->}
    \chemfig{*6((-[:-150])-(-[:-135])(-[:-45])-(*5(-(=[:-72]O)-O-(=[:72]O)-))--(-[:135])(-[:45])-(-[:150])=)}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the \phantom is to draw a C that is invisible and I can locate the + and arrow at the height of the invisible C?

Comment: @some one Yes. "First atom’s role" in manual.

Answer (score 0):

Put a marker "@{a}" on the vertical bond and put an invisible arrow out of that point, and then put "+'

\chemfig does not have to be between $...$

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart \chemfig{C(-[:50])(-[:130])=[:-150]C(-[:150])-[@{a}:-90]C(-[:-150])=[:-30]C(-[:-50])(-[:-130])}
\arrow(@{a}--){0}[0,1]\+ 
\chemfig{[:144]O*5(-(=[:72]O)-=-(=[:-72]O)-)} 
\arrow{->} \chemfig{*6((-[:-150])-(-[:-135])(-[:-45])-(*5(-(=[:-72]O)-O-(=[:72]O)-))--(-[:135])(-[:45])-(-[:150])=)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]